# How can I make my video restart automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, video

I need to put one function more in my script to make my video start automatically when it's finished. This is script. I know probably that I have to set the `currentTime` property back to 0. How can I configure it in my script? There are other ways to achieve that? I am using this [jQuery Plugin](http://www.georgepaterson.com/sandbox/jquery-html5-video-background-demo/)

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('dl').toggle();
                $('h2').bind('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).next('dl').slideToggle(500, function() {
                        $('.video-background').videobackground('resize');
                    });
                });
                $('.main').prepend('<div class="video-background"></div>');
                $('.video-background').videobackground({
                    videoSource: [['video/TimeLapse_Barcelona.mp4', 'video/mp4'],
                        ['video/TimeLapse_Barcelona.webm', 'video/webm'], 
                        ['video/TimeLapse_Barcelona.theora.ogv', 'video/ogg']], 
                    controlPosition: '#main',
                    poster: 'video/big-buck-bunny.jpg',
                    loadedCallback: function() {
                        $(this).videobackground('mute');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Not sure if you're willing to use youtube, however it has this function built in. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TU7YqUGr0Ts

Comment: how can i set it? could you show me an example? so appreciate

Comment: Read the doc ! http://www.georgepaterson.com/sandbox/jquery-html5-video-background-demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the plugin parameters it states

> **loop**: Video loop attribute boolean. Default is false.

Setting that to `true`, will make the video loop..

---

```
$('.video-background').videobackground({
                videoSource: [['video/TimeLapse_Barcelona.mp4', 'video/mp4'],
                    ['video/TimeLapse_Barcelona.webm', 'video/webm'], 
                    ['video/TimeLapse_Barcelona.theora.ogv', 'video/ogg']], 
                controlPosition: '#main',
                loop: true, // ADDED THIS LINE !
                poster: 'video/big-buck-bunny.jpg',
                loadedCallback: function() {
                    $(this).videobackground('mute');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

**loop:**

Video loop attribute boolean. Default is false.

So try :

```
$('.video-background').videobackground({loop:true});
```